# Regex applied to Replace function on XSLT 3 not working

Tags: xslt, saxon, xslt-3.0

I believe this is a simple problem, I'm trying to apply a Regex to my replace method in a variable in XSLT 3 (I'm also using Saxon (latest version)). I know it is possible to use replace with a regex but it seems that the regex I'm trying to use is wrong, it works in Java but not there on XSLT.

Here is my variable with the replace method:

```
<xsl:variable name="namePrefix" select="replace(@name, '/(.*_[^_]+)/')" />
```

I want this variable `namePrefix` to return me an specific part of the name of my Node (found under the attribute @name), here is an Name Example:

```
ALBA_MASTER_FIX_Test
```

I want this regex and replace methode to return to my variable everything before the last `_`.

I would like to know wheter I'm applying the regex correctly? Or if I should do it in a different way or use a different regex. Thx :)

Comment: The "/" characters to delimit a regex are used in some host languages, but not in XPath/XSLT. And replace() requires 3 parameters: the input string, the regex, and the replacement string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> everything before the last `_`.

I believe that could be simply:

```
replace(@name, '_[^_]*$', '')
```

---

Alternatively, you could use something like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="tokenize(@name, '_')[position() lt last()]" separator="_"/>
```

Comment: I would tend to use the tokenize() solution. I'm always suspicious of regular expressions that involve look-ahead and back-tracking.

Comment: @MichaelKay But there's no look-ahead or back-tracking here?

Comment: The regex involves lookahead in that when you're on a `_`, you have to scan forward and get a failure if you find another `_`, at which point (in the absence of a rather smart optimizer) you have to go back to the character after the previous `_`. It's not too bad in this case because you're only visiting each character twice; but tokenize() will only visit it once.

Comment: @MichaelKay I thought you meant lookahead in the sense of https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Thanks for the input, I actually decided to use the tokenize since like @MichaelKay mentioned it is less "suspicious". It is working perfectly now.

Comment: @ThiagoBenkendorf, if input string not having 'underScore', then tokenize will reuslts empty text. Better to use 'replace' method. If all inputs must contains 'underScore', then go for 'tokenize'.

Answer (score 0):

This works in the very useful xslt3fiddle based upon SaxonJS:

```
replace(@name, '(.*)_(.*)', '$1')
```

Can see used in this stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
  
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  
  <xsl:variable name="inputElement" as="element()" >
    <input name="ALBA_MASTER_FIX_Test" />
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
    <output value="{replace($inputElement/@name, '(.*)_(.*)', '$1')}" />
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

with output

```
<output value="ALBA_MASTER_FIX"/>
```